# why testflight version not showing updated version on device

Tags: ios, version, testflight

I have released few test flight releases like Version 1.0(1.0) # 30 , 1.0(1.0) # 31 and 1.0(1.0) # 32. Sent Email notifications also. But , For many they are able to see app version as 1.0 [image]

like this... Not able to see updated versions. Help me to get solution for this... thanks

Comment: you only allow to upload the maximum 30 build in one version.. Then after you upload the build then replace with the last Build you have uploaded

Comment: ho! how can we change version? any possibility to change version for released build?

Comment: You can change the version of application from Project setting or info.plist file then after you upload with the new version for testing

Comment: Do I need to change bundle version or Bundle versions string , short ? i tried bundle version its not reflecting?

Comment: you have to change the version no. form project setting as well as info.plsit so total 4 places to change the version number 2 in info.plist and 2 in project settings

Comment: Its coming fine for others except few people... still its coming as above.:(. clueless!

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

1.0(1.0) # 31
this basically means that you have uploaded the 31st build of the same 1.0 version of the app. This #31 is only for the developer to differentiate the build from other build of same version 1.0(1.0).

Solution:
The recommended way to set the versions is shown below in the screenshot. 
Version 1.0 Build 1.0.3 will show as 1.0 (1.0.3) on Testflight. Everytime you upload a new build, you should increment the Build number.
For example: Build 1.0.4 will display as 1.0 (1.0.4) and so on.

Hope this helps!

[image: Sample screenshot showing the correct way to set version]